# Symmetric power of an etale map of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ an etale morphism of smooth curves over $k$. Let $f^{[n]}\colon X^{[n]} \rightarrow Y^{[n]}$ be the induced morphism on $n$-th symmetric powers. Is $f^{[n]}$ also etale? Clearly, affine $X$ and $Y$ suffice for the purposes of the question.

It seems from VA.'s answer to [Smoothness of Symmetric Powers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10349/smoothness-of-symmetric-powers) that the answer is yes, but his argument is too terse for me; in particular, I don't understand how to harmlessly pass to formal completions. I would be grateful if someone could give a more detailed explanation.

EDIT. As abx noted in the comments, my question is based on a false expectation. Give this, let me modify the question: how does one prove that $X^{[n]}$ is $k$-smooth by reducing to the $X = \mathbb{A}^1_k$ case? That is, how to carry out the reduction?

Comment: This is obviously false. Say $f$ has degree 2, and $f^{-1}(y)=\{x_1,x_2\} $; then the fiber of $f^{[2]}$ above $(y,y)$ consists of 3 points $(x_1,x_1)$, $(x_2,x_2)$ and $(x_1,x_2)$, while $f^{[2]}$ has degree 4.

Comment: As abx said, this is false.  A slightly expanded explanation is that it is true for product, but not symmetric product.  That's because the symmetric group doesn't act freely.

Comment: Answer to the EDIT question: locally for the étale topology, $X$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, hence $X^{[n]}$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{A}^1)^{[n]}\cong \mathbb{A}^n$, and therefore smooth.

Comment: @abx: The "hence" part of your comment is precisely what I am asking to explain. I understand the general strategy that you mention, but my question is: how to make it precise?

Comment: This is an easy exercise, you should be able to do it by yourself. First reduce to the case of a point $(x,\ldots ,x)$ in $X^{[n]}$, then choose a map $u:X\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$ étale at $x$, and show that $u^{[n]}$ is étale at $(x,\ldots ,x)$.

Comment: @abx: I have already tried to do this along the lines you indicate but I don't find it easy. That is why I am asking this here. Your comments do not answer my question.